# Cannot get the border-bottom width of an element using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following simple code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('image_1');
style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
borderBottom = style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom');
console.log(borderBottom);
```

```css
#image_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 340px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image_1">hello</div>
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamedminaee/a8t4nj01/3/).

Any idea?

Comment: Your example code alerts/logs the correct value, which is all three elements of the border. If you just want the width, just get the width, `border-bottom-width`. http://jsfiddle.net/3r8xzf9j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fix your css it works fine. You declare the bottom width but not the other required values for the border property so the border doesn't actually exist in your example.

Check this out:

```
#image_1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 340px;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr19jbwu/)

Comment: No need to change the CSS, just querying 'border-bottom-width' instead of 'border-bottom' gives the correct answer (1px).

Comment: Sorry, @Harris is right, you do need to fix the CSS. `border-bottom: 1px`  is invalid. change that to `border-bottom: 1px transparent solid` and `style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom')` to `style.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width')`

Answer (score 0):

Your css is invalid. `border-bottom` should be in the format `width style color`.

If you change your css to `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` you can then get the width and the styling will be visible as well.

Comment: No need to change the CSS, just querying 'border-bottom-width' instead of 'border-bottom' gives the correct answer (1px). Also, the order doesn't matter in the value of `border`. It could be `color width style` or `style color width` as well.

Comment: You can put the elements of `border` in any order, and leave out ones you don't want to change. See [the examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

Comment: @marekful Are you sure this is the case? I don't believe this is correct unless you have already previously defined the other border properties? It does not work in the fiddle. And yes, the order of the properties doesn't matter, but convention is typically a good thing, thats why it _should_ be in that format, not _must_.